# Conditional email trigger on Model attribute update (Devise & Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm still learning Rails, and using Devise.  Currently I am working on a bug/ticket logging system.  I'n this system we have tickets created by a user, assigned to another user and all users that can view it can post a reply on it.

I want to trigger an email when a user changes the status of a ticket to closed.

HOWEVER, if you are the creator (of the ticket) and you closed it, you do not want an email, but you want to email the user its assigned to.  Likewise, if you are the assignee and you close it, you do not want to email, but you do want to email the creator.  If you are neither creator or assignee, you still do not want an email, but you do want to email the other two.

The email will be a small notification noting ticket #**_** is closed.

I am a bit tripped up as to where this code should go.  There is no new code in the controller but I added a before_update :email_update in my ticket model.

```
def email_update 
  #status field is changed
  if status_changed? && status.description == "Closed"
   if(current_user != assigned_to)
      UserMailer.new_ticket_admin(assigned_to, self).deliver
    end

    if(current_user != user)
      UserMailer.new_ticket_admin(user, self).deliver
    end
  end       
end
```

But, is this not bad practice to access the current user in one of the models?  What would be a better approach?

Comment: try changing self to current_user

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure, but I don't think that you can access `current_user` in the model. Even if you could, might I suggest an alternative. Instead, I would use a `closed_by_id` attribute where it is the `current_user's` ID. This way you can also track who closed a ticket. From here, you can check to see if the ticket is closed and if the creator of the ticket's ID is equal to the `closed_by_id`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you have a creator and a 'closer' (or whatever you want to call that user). Within your user model you want to have something like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requested_by, class_name: 'User' # foreign_key requested_by_id
  belongs_to :closed_by, class_name: 'User' # foreign_key closed_by_id

  def close(user)
    self.closed_by = user
    self.save
  end

  # bonus method
  def closed?
    closed_by?
  end
end

def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, foreign_key: 'requested_by_id'
  has_many :closed_tickets, foreign_key: 'closed_by_id'
end
```

And for your controller something like:

```
class TicketController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @ticket = current_user.tickets.build params[:ticket]
  end

  def close
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.close current_user
  end
end
```

This way there is no need to have current_user within your model. Which probably solves your challege.